# Old/New Testament Jewish culture: On or Off topic?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by [What portion of his income would a Jew following the sacrificial laws give?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-portion-of-his-income-would-a-jew-following-the-sacrificial-laws-give):

Are questions about Old/New Testament Jewish culture and life on topic on this site?

Or should we migrate them to Judaism.SE (with their permission, of course).

Answer (score 9):

I would be inclined to consider questions on Jewish life and culture on topic **when they are asked in conjunction with a question related to Christianity**.

According to this test, the question I linked to above would be **off topic**, but [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/718/which-cup-of-wine-did-jesus-tell-his-disciples-to-drink-during-the-last-supper) I would consider **on topic**, since it's asking about Jewish culture in the context of communion, which is decidedly Christian.