# How can I ask about the Christian response to atheist arguments in a way that would be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd really like to ask some apologetics related questions. It would be a tragedy if wavering Christians left us because we failed to provide answers, especially to the easier and more common challenges. However, I'm a little concerned about the wording.

Which of the following would be the appropriate phrasing to make this question on-topic here?

1. What is the Christian response to [Dawkins's Boeing 747 argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Boeing_747_gambit)?
2. Does Dawkins's Boeing 747 argument demonstrate that the Christian God doesn't exist? If not, why?
3. What are the counter-arguments against Dawkins's Boeing 747 argument?
4. Does Dawkins's Boeing 747 argument apply to the Christian conception of God?
5. What are the Christian arguments against Dawkins's Boeing 747 argument? Are there any atheist counter-arguments?

Answer (score 9):

The ultimate problem is that you're looking for some singular overarching Christian response to *anything*. This site's foundational principal is basically that there isn't one.

That said, if you were to narrow these questions to a *specific group* or Christians who share a theological identity or similar philosophical viewpoints (you'll have to do some research to figure out which group your interested in), some of these questions would be on topic. That said, many of these are more philosophical than they are doctrinal and may have a tough go here.

The core purpose of this site is *not* apologetic (though apologetics is on topic). We start with apriori assumptions of truth here and we acknowledge them. The core purpose of this site is to ask and respond to questions about Christianity, namely Christian doctrine. So we're asking about what churches and Christians teach. Apologetics will inevitably come up, but they face the same restrictions on question framing that every other question on this site should be put up against. Is there a defined viewpoint (ie what is the OP's definition of truth, and what constitutes evidence to them).

Comment: Thank you. I had always thought that all Christians believed God to be eternal, perhaps I erred there. Would it be better if I phrased it as: "What is the response of Christians who believe that God has XXXX attributes to YYYY atheist's argument?"

Comment: Hmm perhaps scriptural apologetics would be a better fit here? e.g. Does XXXX verse and YYYY verse contradict each other?

Comment: @TwilightSparkle asking for a scripture proof of a concept is OK, asking if scripture x proves concept y is not.

Answer (score 2):

This is general philosophy; it is not about Christianity and responses to it are not necessarily Christian, though they would be theist. We have a specific close reason for exactly this kind of question:

> General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer.

Here's why:

They are not specifically asking for something that is Christian, though some Christians may hold it. Now going through your questions above, here's how I think they would be received:

1. There is no blanket Christian response, and as I have already said, any response is not necessarily Christian. Closed as too broad.
2. The question is about Dawkin's argument and its applications, not about Christianity. Closed "because it is not about Christianity."
3. The question is about counter arguments to Dawkin's argument, not Christianity. Closed "because it is not about Christianity."
4. The question is about Dawkin's argument and its applications. It is the same as question two. Closed "because it is not about Christianity".
5. Same as question one. Closed as too broad.

I don't think you will be able to ask questions like this on the site without them being closed.

Another issue is that, typically, these kinds of questions on atheism (and evolution, somewhat) are breeding grounds for debate and trolls. We deleted one recently because it was so bad.

Please see [a list of template questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/3961) that the community finds acceptable.

Also, [see this meta post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3479/3961) that is on a similar topic.

Comment: I think you make a good point about these kinds of questions being a breeding ground for trolls and debate. I hope the community will find some happy medium between helping wavering Christians and the risk of attracting trolls.

I have to disagree with (1) and (5) though. All Christian responses by all major philosophers and apologists can be fit into 1 side of an A4 paper.

Comment: Also, my feeling is that the atheists.SE site died because these kinds of debates are sterile, from which ever side you look at them.

Comment: @Benjol Yes, but we like to joke that it's because no one believed in it.